# How to change the input value to default?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I fix this problem?
I want when the number is written inside the box, and it goes out of focus, the text and the number do not overlap and the box returns to its default state.

[image: problem]

**Code:**

```css
.left {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #eef5db;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 2px solid #eef5db;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 30rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.input-lable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.input:focus+.input-lable {
  transform: translate(0, -80px) scale(0.8);
  color: #000000;
}

.input:is(:focus, .valid) {
  outline-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="left">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="age" id="name" class="input" />
      <lable for="name" class="input-lable">Enter your guess ...</lable>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <input type="button" value="Check" class="check" />
      <input type="button" value="Again" class="again" />
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<lable>` is an invalid HTML5 tag. Use `<label>` if that's what you meant.

Comment: Don't know if this will fix your problem, but make sure to spell the `label` tag correctly in your HTML code.

Comment: Also, why don't you use the INPUT's `placeholder` attribute? `<input type="text" palceholder="Enter your guess">`

Comment: What is `type="age"` ??? You mean `type="number"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to create javascript function & call them on onClick

```css
.left {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #eef5db;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 2px solid #eef5db;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 30rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.input-lable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.input:focus+.input-lable {
  transform: translate(0, -80px) scale(0.8);
  color: #000000;
}

.input:is(:focus, .valid) {
  outline-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="left">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="age" id="name" class="input" />
      <lable for="name" class="input-lable">Enter your guess ...</lable>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <!-- <input type="button" value="Check" class="check" />
      <input type="button" value="Again" class="again" /> -->
      <input type="button" value="Check" class="check"  onclick="checkClick();" />
      <input type="button" value="Again" class="again" onclick="againClick();" />
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

<script>
  function checkClick(){
    if(document.getElementById("name").value.trim() != ''){
      document.getElementById("name").focus();
    }
  } 

  function againClick(){
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
  }
 
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check via Javascript if there is any value in that input, and if so, add a class that prevents shrinking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.left {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #eef5db;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 2px solid #eef5db;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 30rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 30px;
}


.input:is(:focus, .valid) {
  outline-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="left">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="age" id="name" class="input" placeholder="Enter your guess .."/>
      
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <input type="button" value="Check" class="check" />
      <input type="button" value="Again" class="again" />
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try

```css
.left {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #eef5db;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 2px solid #eef5db;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 30rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.input-lable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.input:focus+.input-lable {
  transform: translate(0, -80px) scale(0.8);
  color: #000000;
}

.input:is(:focus, .valid) {
  outline-color: #000000;
}

/* Added this line */
.input:not(:focus) {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="left">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="age" id="name" class="input" />
      <lable for="name" class="input-lable">Enter your guess ...</lable>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <input type="button" value="Check" class="check" />
      <input type="button" value="Again" class="again" />
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to delete the input value, I think better use Javascript, hope this work!